# I need to extract part of a variable string with ruby, how can this be done?

Tags: ruby

I have a string as follows:

```
"/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/34b4209a-5d97-11e3-9fb6-3d0f528c3bba/"
```

I want to extract the bit between Account/ and /Call, in other words: "MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD"

I have tried

```
string.delete('/v1/Account/')
```

with no success.

'/v1/Account/' will always be the same and '/Call/' will always be the same but the remainder of the string to the right of '/Call/' will vary.

How can I do this guys? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=> str = "/v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/Call/34b4209a-5d97-11e3-9fb6-3d0f528c3bba/"
=> str.split('/')[3]
=> "MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD"
```

Comment: just very simple way!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be a substring:

```
id = string[12..31]
```

If the pattern changes, you can try out a regex:

```
id = string.gsub(/\/[\/]+\/Account\/([^\/]+)\/.*/, '\1')
```

Comment: I had problems with this approach but thank you fro your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

use regex `String#match`

```
string.match(/\/v1\/Account\/(.*)\/Call\//)[1]
```

or

```
string[12..string.index("/Call/")-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that you can use

```
%r{/Account/(.*)/Call}
```

instead of escaping all backslashes. Yet another possible solution using String#scan:

```
string.scan(%r{/Account/(.*)/Call}).join
```